# How can Firefox masquerade as Chrome?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser, browser-addons

I have access to Firefox but not Chrome under XP. I would like extensions to make it more Chrome-like: in particular,

1: A tabbed theme that works like Chrome.

2: One address/search bar that will go to URLs and submit search queries appropriately.

(I have already installed "Download Statusbar.")

I am looking on a relatively superficial level; I'm not hoping to simulate V8 or Chrome's screaming render times. But I would like a setup that minimally breaks the illusion for someone accustomed to Chrome.

Comment: It's funny that you mention render times, I tend to get better results with firefox in that regard. I know there's an extension to do a google search from URL bar entries, I'll look for it real quick.

Comment: An alternative solution would be to use [Google Chrome Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable).

Answer (score 4):

1. [FXChrome](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fxchrome/) theme for Firefox.
2. [Omnibar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/omnibar/) search integration into the address bar.